# An approximation as accurate as $\mathcal{o}(h^2+k^2)$ for $f(h, k)$ where $\displaystyle f(x,y) = \sqrt{1+4x^2+y^2}$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Give an approximation as accurate as $\mathcal{o}(h^2+k^2)$ for $f(h, k)$ where $\displaystyle f(x,y) = \sqrt{1+4x^2+y^2}$.

To clarify, I'm asked an expansion of $f$ at $(h, k)$ that's as accurate as $\mathcal{o}(h^2+k^2)$ $\leftarrow$ what's this?

I know $\displaystyle f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0)+\left(\Delta x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\Delta y  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left( \Delta x \Delta y\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}+\Delta x \Delta y\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}\right)+\cdots$ evaluated at $(x, y) = (x_0, y_0)$, where $\Delta x = x-x_0$ and $\Delta y = y-y_0$. Is this correct and how do you apply it?

Do I replace $x_0$ with $h$ and $y_0$ with $k$, and it's fine to still have $x$ and $y$ in the expansion for $f(h, k)$?

Also, what's the meaning of $\mathcal{o}(h^2+k^2)$ and how does it differ from $f(h^2, k^2)$?

Comment: The meaning of $o(h^2+k^2)$ is that you are supposed to find an approximaton $\tilde f(x,y)$ for $f(x,y)$ such that $\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(h,k)-\tilde f(h,k)}{h^2+k^2}=0$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks, that was clarified it! Can I ask, does $\mathcal{o}(h^2, k^2)$ mean the same thing as $\mathcal{o}(h^2+k^2)$ as well? Or is that not a notation that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a neighbourhood of the origin
$$ \sqrt{1+z} = 1+\frac{z}{2}+o(z) $$
hence
$$ \sqrt{1+4x^2+y^2} = 1+2x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2 + o(4x^2+y^2) $$
and you just have to show that $o(4x^2+y^2)=o(x^2+y^2)$, that is pretty simple.
No gradients, no Hessians really need to be computed.

Comment: Thank you. That's very nice! So the answer to my question would be $f(h, k) = 1+2h^2+\frac{1}{2}k^2 + \mathcal{o}(h^2+k^2)$. If that's right, can I ask, how does the method I was trying to use achieve the answer? I'm not asking for a solution using that - just a little outline, if you please (like what to replace with $\Delta x$ etc. I'm guessing $\Delta x = h, ~ \Delta y = k$? And after partial differentiation you sub $x = h, ~ y = k$? If I do that, I don't get $1+2h^2+\frac{1}{2}k^2 $). I get a series where every term contains an expression under a radical.

Comment: @J.Doe: you may also exploit the two variables Taylor expansion at the origin by computing a gradient and a Hessian, but you'll end up with the same expression, of course.

Comment: Thanks again (sorry I can't even give you an upvote).